# How to use preg_match to search for symbols

Tags: php

How do i find matches with any of -+/* symbols using preg_match?

I try

```
$stroke = '21+64';
$pattern = '/[+-/*]/';

preg_match($pattern, $stroke, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

but it doesn't work..
Thank you.

Comment: `$pattern = '\[\+\-/\*]/';`   YOu have to escape the + - * and / symbols by prefixing with a \

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with that pattern:

```
/[+\-\*]/
```

You have to "escape" the `-` and the `*`, and you do that with a preceding "back slash" (`\`).